# How to know if when using "on duplicate key update" a row was inserted or updated?

Tags: mysql

We have a database that gets updated everyday at midnight with a cronjob, we get new data from an external XML.

What we do is that we insert all the new content and in case there is a duplicated key we update that field.

```
INSERT INTO table (id, col1, col2, col3)
values (id_value, val1, val2, val3),
(id_value, val1, val2, val3),
(id_value, val1, val2, val3),
(id_value, val1, val2, val3),
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
col1 = VALUES (col1), 
col2 = VALUES (col2), 
col3 = VALUES (col3);
```

What we want to know is which rows have actually been inserted, meaning we want to have a list of the new items. is there any query that might return the new inserts? Basically we will need to get all the new ID's and not the number of new insertions.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add an `update_count INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1` column and change your query:

```
INSERT
INTO    table (id, col1, col2, col3)
VALUES
(id_value, val1, val2, val3),
(id_value, val1, val2, val3,),
(id_value, val1, val2, val3),
(id_value, val1, val2, val3),
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE 
        col1 = VALUES (col1), 
        col2 = VALUES (col2), 
        col3 = VALUES (col3),
        update_count = update_count + 1;
```

You can also increment it in a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger which will allow you to keep the query as is.

Comment: Thanks Quassnoi, great idea, I did use a new column called udpated and applied your idea with different approach that actually worked great for me, please review your answer for the modifications I made and give me some feedback. It worked great thanks.

Answer (score 40):

You can get this information at the time of the insert/update by examining the number of affected rows in the result set.

MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) states:

> With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if
>   the row is inserted as a new row and 2 if an existing row is updated.

You'll need to combine ROW_COUNT with LAST_INSERT_ID to get your answer and insert one row at a time.

Comment: This helps to ascertain *how many* rows were inserted vs updated, but not which were which...

Comment: Yes we thought of that but I need to know the primary key of the rows inserted, not the number or count of rows inserted.

Comment: @EddyXP, you'll need to combine ROW_COUNT with LAST_INSERT_ID to get your answer and insert one row at a time.

Comment: Keep in mind that if an update occurs but with the same previous data, affected-rows will give 0.

Answer (score 0):

I can say How I did in PHP:

1) Simple query SELECT MAX(id) and remember it to $max_id from table before Insert On Duplicate.

2) Then during the update process collect ID of affected rows (no mater new or existed): $ids[] = mysql_insert_id();

3) Then $inserted_rows = max($ids)-$max_id;

4) Updated rows = count($ids_srt)-$inserted_rows

```
$max_id = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(id) from table");
$max_id = mysql_result($max_id, 0);

// !!! prepare here 'insert on duplicate' query in a cycle

$result=mysql_query($query);
$ids[] = mysql_insert_id();

// finish inserting and collecting affected ids and close cycle

$inserted_rows = max($ids)- $max_id;
$updated_rows = count($ids)- $inserted_rows
```