# How to insert record if there are no duplicate in the previous query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 2 insert queries that I need to execute. each query will insert data in a different table. The first query has ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause. What I need to do is to prevent the second query from running is the first one cause an update due to a DUPLICATE KEY.

here is my code currently.

```
    $insertEvent = $db->processQuery('INSERT INTO calendar_events (start_on, end_on, subject, owner_id, created_by, phone_call_id, status )
                                        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE start_on = ?, end_on =?, status = ? ',
                                        array($start, $end, $subject, $owner, $created_by, $phone_call_id, $status, $start, $end, $status) );   
    $event_id = $db->lastinsertid();

    $insertEvent2 = $db->processQuery('INSERT INTO calendar_attendees (event_id, owner_id) VALUE (?, ?)', array($event_id, $owner));
```

I only want to execute $insertEvent2 only if $insertEvent created a new record otherise ignore the second statement.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know if when using "on duplicate key update" a row was inserted or updated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709380/how-to-know-if-when-using-on-duplicate-key-update-a-row-was-inserted-or-update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) syntax on your second `INSERT`, so that your query will look like

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO calendar_attendees (event_id, owner_id) VALUES (?, ?)
```

Make sure that you have a `UNIQE` constraint on `(event_id, owner_id)`.

*BTW you have a typo in your second insert. It should be `VALUES` instead of `VALUE`.*

Comment: What if the event already existed in `calendar_events`, but with no (or different) attendees in `calendar_attendees`?

Comment: This is a good solution. I was not sure if there is a way to add a condition in the query to execute the second query only if the first query was executed. But you solution works. Thanks :)