# PHP check if MYSQL query was an insert or update

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple MYSQL query:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1,col2) VALUES ('1','2') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = '1', col2 = '2'
```

I use PHP PDO statements to query the database. Is there a way to know if the query executed resulted into a new inserted row or an existing was updated?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/10709458/4099592

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know if when using "on duplicate key update" a row was inserted or updated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709380/how-to-know-if-when-using-on-duplicate-key-update-a-row-was-inserted-or-update)

Comment: Get last insert id. In case of update it will be null

Answer (score 1):

One way to do so is to get the number of rows before executing the query, then get the number of rows after executing the query, if they're not equal, it means a new row was inserted and if they are equal, it means a row was updated.

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'TABLE_NAME'";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$number_of_rows_before = $row['Rows'];
// Do your query here, afterwards
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$number_of_rows_after = $row['Rows'];
// If condition
if($number_of_rows_before == $number_of_rows_after) // Update was executed
else // a new row was inserted.
```

Comment: very inefficient compared to using mysql_affected_rows

Answer (score 1):

Just use *mysqli_affected_rows*,it returns the number of rows affected by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query.

From PHP documentation:

> In the case of "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" queries, the return value will be 1 if an insert was performed, or 2 for an update of an existing row.

see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

From Mysql manual:

> "With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if
> the row is inserted as a new row and 2 if an existing row is updated."

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

This is the most reliable way to do it.

Comment: This won't work for `PHP PDO statements` (which OP is using). The equivalent only returns a count.

Comment: mysqli_affected_rows return 1 if new row is inserted 
                               return 2 if row is updated 
                               return 0 if row is not updated

Answer (score 0):

maybe you put the answer right into the query like:

INSERT INTO table (col1,col2, col_type) VALUES ('1','2','inserted') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = '1', col2 = '2', col_type = 'updated'